# How do I remove an operational attribute using ldaptemplate

Tags: java, spring, ldap, openldap, spring-ldap

I need to remove the operational attribute from the policy overlay called `pwdAccountLockedTime`

I followed [this Q&A](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/site/faq.html#remove-oper-attr) which suggest way number 2:

Use `LdapTemplate#modifyAttributes(Name, ModificationItem[])` directly, manually building the `ModificationItem` array.

Here's my code:

```
Name dn = buildDn(user);
DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);
ModificationItem[] modificationItems;
modificationItems = new ModificationItem[1];
modificationItems[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContextAdapter.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE,
                                            new BasicAttribute(
                                                 "pwdAccountLockedTime", dn));
ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn,modificationItems);
```

I checked the user and that attribute still exist there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your intent is to unlock an account which has been locked by too many incorrect password attempts in OpenLdap.

If the user account is locked (pwdLockout is TRUE) then it may be [unlocked by an administrator](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/ppolicy.html#policy-unlock) using either of the following procedures:

Delete the operational attribute pwdAccountLockedTime. This procedure allows the user to continue to use the current password and is only effective if the password has not expired.

Add the operational attribute pwdReset with a value of either TRUE or FALSE. FALSE is only effective if the password has not expired and has the same effect as deleting pwdAccountLockedTime.

In most openLDAP versions, you can remove the pwdAccountLockedTime.

Some versions may require using the ManageDIT control. Both of these assuming you have proper permissions.

According to rfc4512 section 3.4, "Not all operational attributes are user modifiable."

-jim

Comment: delete pwdAccountLockedTime is what I am willing to do. But I am trying to find my way how to do it. As you can see in my question I tried but it didn't work. you have any idea how?

Comment: But were you bound to LDAP as an administrative account?

Comment: Try some known code like Apache Directory Studio and use an Administrator account. Oh, and never use JNDI use a current good LDAP SDK like https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/ -jim

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the pwdAccountLockedTime attribute then you have to specify admin credentials while configuring LDAP. Users don't have access to delete operational attributes.you can take below code as a reference.

```
       Name dn = buildDn(pvo);

       DirContextOperations context = ldapTemplate.lookupContext(dn);
       ModificationItem[] modificationItems;
       modificationItems = new ModificationItem[1];


       modificationItems[0] =new ModificationItem(DirContext.REMOVE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("pwdAccountLockedTime"));

   ldapTemplate.modifyAttributes(dn,modificationItems);
```

Note: buildDn() is a separate method.

```
  protected Name buildDn(PersonVo p) {
    return LdapNameBuilder.newInstance(BASE_DN)
      .add("","")    // add your root
      .add("", "")    // add your root
      .add("cn", p.getFullname())
      .build();
  }
```

I am getting this PersonVo object from the postman, based on that I am building Dn.

Here is the Configuration code

@Configuration
public class Config {

```
@Bean
public LdapContextSource ldapContextSource()
{
    LdapContextSource lcs= new LdapContextSource();
    lcs.setUrl("Your url");
    lcs.setUserDn("yourDn");
    lcs.setPassword("yourpassword");
    return lcs;
}
```

}

If you won't specify the admin credentials this code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Operational attributes are for the LDAP server, not for applications. They are read-only to applications.

However this specific attribute can be changed by an administrator account. The only other way to change it is for the lockout to expire . Otherwise [only a password administrator can unlock the account](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10): see #5.3.3.

Comment: Let's assume I am password administrator. how can i Unlock that? programatilly? or? btw did you check the link I posted? They answer that we are able to delete it in workaround way. Trying to achieve that

Comment: The link you posted must be incorrect. It violates a primary principle of LDAP. Anything you do when bound as an administrator is an admin action.

Comment: So how can I bind as an administrator programticlly and unlock a locked user? this is requirement that our management system suppose to support